# Chaining with Pagedown's PreBlockGamut

Tags: javascript, regex, pagedown

I've tried searching online, but it seems that topics covering this subject are very scarce, and -- short of the information on [PageDown's Google Code page](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown), there doesn't seem to be too much more on the topic (much less anything comprehensive)

I'm trying to add custom formatting to PageDown using either the `preBlockGamut` or the `preSpanGamut`, neither of which are accomplishing what I am hoping for it to do.

What I'm trying to do should be simple: I want any text that appears between two tildes to be formatted between `<del>` tags.

I have tried various ways so far with the `preBlockGamut`, with this one providing the closest thing to what I'm looking for:

```
converter.hooks.chain("preBlockGamut", function (text, rbg) {
  return text.replace(/~(.*?)~/, function (whole, inner) {
    return "<del>" + inner +"</del>";
  });
});
```

This works only *somewhat* as expected, in that it surrounds the **first** instance of the text like so: `<del>T{inner text}</del>T`. This only happens on the first instance, and I also have  no idea where the T's are coming from because -- so far as I can tell with my code -- it isn't anywhere in the regex or the replacement.

I know that `preBlockGamut` should be used for block-level statements, and so I've tried a similar approach with `preSpanGamut`, with no better luck.

Does anyone on here have any experience with this that can possibly provide some insight into this issue? I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I can't seem to figure out where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending a while looking through PageDown's files, I found the source of my issue.

`Markdown.Converter.js` has the following lines:

```
// attacklab: Replace ~ with ~T
// This lets us use tilde as an escape char to avoid md5 hashes
// The choice of character is arbitray; anything that isn't
// magic in Markdown will work.
text = text.replace(/~/g, "~T");
```

This executes before the `preBlockGamut` hook would take affect, resulting in `~{inner text}~` becoming `~T{inner text}~T` which then parsed as `<del>T{inner text}</del>T`.